Is There Difference of opinion Over the statement of Al-Mawardi
Is There a difference of opinion in Hanbali Madhab regarding the matter mentioned here related to Ahlul Ahad because I found in some Fiqh book that they permit captivity. OR I am just confusing it with something else?


وَيَجُوزُ شِرَاءُ أَوْلَادِ أَهْلِ الْعَهْدِ مِنْهُمْ وَلَا يَجُوزُ
سَبْيُهُمْ


الأحكام السلطانية الماوردي

Could you provide more information on the fiqh book you refer to that allows captivity?

@Medi1Saif
(10/388 الإنصاف في معرفة الراجح من الخلاف - ت التركي)

@Medi1Saif
الإنصاف في معرفة الراجح من الخلاف - ت الفقي (4/215)

@Medi1Saif
كتاب شرح منتهى الإرادات لابن النجار - معونة أولي النهى4/436
